# Change of variables question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is there a change of variables I can make so that I can get
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2 + \cos\theta}d\theta = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2 + \cos\theta}d\theta?$$ I've been trying $u = \theta - \pi$ and other similar things and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It might help to draw the function -- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28cos%28x%29%2B2%29

Comment: If you know some complex analysis, namely residue theorem, you can do it and I could help, just let me know.

Comment: Why are people interpreting this question as asking how to evaluate the integral when it clearly doesn't ask that?

Answer (score 1):

Try $\theta=2\pi-u{{{{{}}}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to evaluate this integral. I'll provide a sketch below.

Consider the integral $$J := \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x} \tag{1}$$

Since there's a singularity at $x = \pi$, we'll split it into two integrals as 
$$J =  \int_{x = 0}^{x = \pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x} + \int_{x = \pi}^{x = 2\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x} \tag{2}$$

Setting $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$ yields

$$J =  \int_{t = -\infty}^{t = \infty} \frac{dt}{2+\cos t} \tag{3} $$
which simplifies to

$$J = \int_{t = -\infty}^{t = \infty} \frac{2 \ dt}{3 + t^2} \tag{4}$$

Hence $J = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$ and your original integral $I$ is $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$.